# Where do i should save my docker postgres backups?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, backup-strategies

I'm have a docker-compose with a postgres service, currently it only has one service but in the future it will contain more.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres-dev:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dev_db
      POSTGRES_USER: dev_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev_password
    volumes:
      - postgres-dev-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

volumes:
  postgres-dev-data:
```

I learn that if i want to create a backup for this db i should run something like `docker-compose exec --interactive -u <your_postgres_user> <service> pg_dump -Fc <database_name_here> > db.dump`

So, my question is, where is the best place to save this **db.dump**? Is it okey to save it on another volume? What is the best practice to do it?

Is it possible to save it for example in a firebase storage?

Thanks!

I did not try anything yet, i just want to know from experienced people that have done it